# Yii - get translation for another language

Tags: yii, translation

I'm using Yii and it's built in translation functionality.

Now, I need to translate some string depending on a user-setting (correspondence language), without changing the main language.

Means: The page itself is in english.
The user can choose a correspondence language.
The title for the user (Mr./Ms.) should be in the selected correspondence language (e.g. for French it should be Monsieur/Madame).

This can't be really achieved by using `Yii::t('app', 'mr')`.
If there'd be a third variable I could pass to the translator for the desired language, that wouldn't be a problem.
I guess I could set the default-language to the correspondence language before translating the title and change it back afterwards, but that seems a little unpractical?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [TsTranslation](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tstranslation/) extension, which allows to translate dinamic messages and get their translated value by `Yii::t()`: f.e. you can use this `Yii::t($model, 'MrOrMs')`, where `$model` intanceof `CActiveRecord` specific user.